# insert into gives operand should contain 1 column error

Tags: python, mysql, list

i am trying to insert 3 array-lists in 3 columns of mysql table through python code but i am continuously getting error of (1241 'operand should contain 1 column(s)'). I dont know how to fix it.

```
sample_text='E://ahmedrazatg.txt'
conn=pymysql.connect("localhost","root","root","wordnet",use_unicode=True, charset="utf8")
 cursor=conn.cursor()
 file = open(sample_text,'r')
 arr=[]
 surah=[]
 verse=[]
 var1="ahmedraza"
 for line in file.readlines():
    words=re.split(' |/|:|;|,|-RRB-|-LRB-|!|\*|\*\*|``',line)
    words=[line.replace(".","") for line in words]
    surah.append(words[0])
    verse.append(words[2])
    j=4
    while j<len(words):
        arr.append(words[j])
        j+=2
        sql="insert into cmp_translation1(surah_no,verse_no,translation,translator_id)values(%s,%s,%s,%s)"
       data=surah,verse,arr,var1
       r=cursor.execute(sql,data)
conn.commit()
cursor.close()
conn.close()
```

My input file is like this:

```
1|6|Guide us the straight way

2|63|And when We made a covenant with you

2|18|Deaf dumb blind and they cannot
```

I want my output like this:

```
 translation_id|surah_no |verse_no |translation                |translator_id

 1             |       1 |     6    |Guide us the straight way |ahmedraza

 2             |       2 |    63    |We made covenant with you |ahmedraza

 3             |       2 |      18  |Deaf dumb blind cannot tu |ahmedraza
```

Comment: **surah,verse,arr,** are arrays, they should be values, something like **surah[j],verse[j],arr [j],**